# How do I stop my vacuum belt from making a noise and smelling when using it?

Tags: cleaning

Last week I had my [Hover WindTunnel Max Multi-Cyclonic](http://hoover.com/products/details/uh70601/windtunnel-max-multi-cyclonic/) (*Model # UH70601*) vacuuming carpet on the bar floor setting. It started making a thwapping noise and smells like burned rubber when vacuuming with the brushroll on.

I opened up the bottom of the vacuum. When I remove the belt the vacuum doesn't make the noise. Looking at the belt and what is holding it in I don't understand why it is making the noise.

Comment: I can't explain the thwapping noise, but when I've had the burned rubber smell, it came from there being something keeping the roller from spinning freely (hair, string, or similar wrapped on the roller), so the belt was rubbing rather than turning.  So, look at the parts that the belt is transfering power to, not just the belt itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The belt is a wear item - it will need to be replaced occasionally.

Typically, what happens is that the beater will get stuck on something but the motor will continue to run, and the friction of the motor against the belt will cause it to heat up - that's what you're smelling.

Once that happens, it's time to replace the belt.  One trick that might get a bit more life out of it is to reverse the belt, but that probably won't last that long - most belts have grooves on one side to improve friction.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I reversed the belt like you said and that has solved my issue for now :)

Comment: Plan on replacing it every six months or so.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo : 6 months?  Some of us don't even vaccuum that often.

Comment: I don't vacuum that often either.  My wife, however...